# What are the permissible ways to bend but not fold a piece of paper?

Tags: differential-geometry

How can one geometrically characterize the ways of bending/rolling/wiggling (but not folding) an ordinary piece of paper? For example it seems necessary but not sufficient that it be a $C^1$ embedding from an unfolded piece of paper into $\mathbb R^3$. A natural choice seems to be isometric embedding, but then the Nash-Kuiper theorem would imply that I can massage a piece of paper into an arbitrarily small region which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface

Comment: @orangeskid I was hesitant to use curvature as part of the criteria since I don't see why the embedding should have to be twice differentiable. But it looks like this is the right answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you view a piece of paper.  We tend to view it as a 2D object, which ignores its thickness.  If you do that, it has zero volume.  You can then find an embedding that is as continuous as you wish into an arbitrarily small ball in $\Bbb R^3$.  If you acknowledge that the paper has thickness, it has a volume greater than zero, and you can't embed it without overlap in a ball any smaller than that volume.

Comment: Of course there's a trivial obstruction if your paper is thick. The first part of your answer can't be correct since there is no $C^2$ isometric embedding into an arbitrarily small ball.

Comment: Sure there is   You can just fold it back and forth like an accordion.  You can do that as smoothly as you want.  The 1D bump functions show it can be $C^\infty$ if you want.  The curvature gets high but stays finite.

Comment: I expect the correct notion should at least be a local isometry so if you have two derivatives the Gauss curvature should be zero.